# Indexable way to set attributes in a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, settings

I have a feeling that this is not the best/most secure way to set attributes but I was trying to find a way to easily set attributes in a CLI program that I am writing in Python.

I have a dunder str output that displays all the attributes and I used that string with enumerate() to number the attributes for selection by the user. I then came up with the below code to access and assign the new values to desired attribute. I know that I have some input validation and cleaning to handle but I want some feedback on the code snippet to know if there is a better way/why it might not be good/ways to improve.

```
class TestClass:
""" test class to show effect of change attribute method """
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    self.b = False
    self.c = 'string'
    self.d = 4.2
    
def setAtrib(self, index, value):
    """ from the dict keys of attributes gained from vars() creates a list for an indexable way to set attributes"""
    keys = list(vars(self).keys()) # creates list of keys
    key = keys[index] # with index gain key value
    vars(self)[key] = value # with key value set attribute to argument value
```

Just finished my first intro to Python class and still getting used to formatting of StackOverflow so please forgive.

Thank you for your time and energy.

Edit - I am creating a time/record keeping program for myself to keep track of my day as a UPS driver.

Comment: Are you ever going to use the actual attributes like `t_instance.b`? If not, why not just store a list and make the class act like a sequence? If you are going to access in both ways, it's probably better to make a mapping from index to attribute name (or vice-versa).

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on your goal here? An example of what the user is inputting from the command line and what you expect to happen/output as the result? You're starting to re-write the wheel here with `setAttrib` which is never good, and I don't see anything here telling me why you're doing that. Also where is vars() defined / coming from?

Comment: @MarkMeyer This is my first larger scale project, which is a personal program to act as a time log for my job as a UPS driver. I have a class which holds all the information relevant to the day. At some point I might create a GUI interface for it but am starting with a CLI program for practice/exercise. I used the method as easier was to add attributes  later on without having to a list. I’m not sure I follow what you mean by “class act like a sequence”.

Comment: @sintax_error, I mean implement `__getitem__()` and `__iter__()` so you can directly index you instances like `t_instance[1]` or `for a in t_instance:`

Comment: @kerasbaz `vars()` is a [Python builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)

Comment: @kerasbaz I didn’t know if it would be good to include more of the code and the rest of the class it works upon. I was trying to keep it simple but I guess the context helps understand the problem.  I know that the setAttrib felt a little cludgie. I am creating a CLI program that is more interactive than just passing args. It will have some menus, write out and read from a text file to save data.

Comment: @MarkMeyer That is good feedback. I am just starting to learn about the many dunder methods inherent to classes. I will look into those.Certainly would have made creating my own method redundant. I lack some of the vocabulary needed to understand what I’m looking for though. As when I first started trying to solve this problem I lacked the vocabulary of ‘attributes’ and searched for class variables which I have learned is something completely different.